# What am I doing wrong in this binding of a dependency property in the code behind (of a view) to a property its viewmodel?

Tags: c#, wpf

A couple of other posts seem to indicate that data can be shared between a View's code behind and viewmodel by binding the dependency property in the code behind and property in the viemodel. Also, I have read that the DP should be in the code behind when itself is being bound in a Main Window/User Control relationship.

The following is from the code behind (SetupUC)

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty UC1Property =
     DependencyProperty.Register(
     "UC1", typeof(string), typeof(SetupUC),
     new FrameworkPropertyMetadata()
     {
        PropertyChangedCallback = OnUC1Changed,
        BindsTwoWayByDefault = true
     });

    public string UC1
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UC1Property); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(UC1Property, value);
        }
    }

public SetupUC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetupViewModel svm = new SetupViewModel();
        this.DataContext = svm;
        Binding binding = new Binding("ViewModelStringProperty") { Source = svm, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, SetupUC.UC1Property, binding);
    }
```

and the viewmodel (SetupViewModel)

```
private string _viewModelStringProperty;
    public string ViewModelStringProperty
    {
        get { return _viewModelStringProperty; }
        set
        {
            _viewModelStringProperty = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ViewModelStringProperty"));
            }
        }
    }

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

In debugging, UC1 seems to always be updated correctly from the Main Window as its changes are reflected in the user control view. However, in the viewmodel, ViewModelStringProperty does not ever seem to be updated - it's always null. Full disclosure(!), the following is how UC1 is bound in the user control XAML

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbx1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="159,22,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding UC1, ElementName=root}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" RenderTransformOrigin="0.017,0.304"/>
```

Again, this part seems to be fine, it's getting data to ViewModelStringProperty in the viewmodel that is not.

Comment: The target of a binding needs to be a DependencyProperty - *ViewModelStringProperty* is not a DP and thus cannot be used as a binding target - use it as source for the binding (and UC1 as target) and establish TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding mode according to your requirments. (Also, your code above which sets the binding programmatically does not compile without errors, right? - How were you able to debug your code if it does not even build?)

Comment: Can I bind a DP to a DP? UC1 is already a dependency property. Yes, the project compiled/built fine; as I mentioned, UC1 is displaying as it is referenced in the XAML snippet. The user control is referenced by a main application (window) and when the data is changed there that is bound to UC1, the user control changes accordingly.

Comment: Yes, you can bind a dependency property to another dependency property. But i advise against turning *ViewModelStringProperty* into a DP - this would require *SetupViewModel* becoming a *DependencyObject* and thus would defeat the purpose and intent of the view models being independent of view-related stuff and technology (*DependencyObject* is part of WPF and base class for all WPF UI elements)

Comment: Regarding *"the project compiled/built fine"*: if your project contains the code exactly as displayed in your question, it **will not** compile. This is a fact. According to the code displayed in your question, `BindingOperations.SetBinding(svm, SetupViewModel.ViewModelStringProperty, binding);` will produce a compiler error. (If it compiles indeed, then this would mean that the declaration of *ViewModelStringProperty* in your real code differs substantially and entirely from what you have shown in your question...)

Comment: elgonzo, you were right, my bad - not sure how/what I cut and pasted above, but it indeed does not compile now.
So, any other suggestions on how this could be accomplished under MVVM?

Comment: Read my very first comment again. There i suggested what you should/could do...

Comment: Okay, I tried that, but ViewModelStringProperty still does not seem to update. I edited my original post to reflect what was changed, but it's also below:

  <br/>
    Binding binding = new Binding("ViewModelStringProperty") { Source = svm, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };  <br/>
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, SetupUC.UC1Property, binding);

Comment: Does UC1 change (set a breakpoint in the OnUC1Changed to verify this)? Note that the binding of TextBox.Text only updates when the textbox loses focus (i.e., you are finished with text input and you tab out of the textbox or click with the mouse on some other control). If you want to have the properties to be updated while you type in text, change the textbox binding to `Text="{Binding UC1, ElementName=root, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"` (check [MSDN doc here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger.aspx))

Comment: Also, note that your binding at the TextBox uses `ElementName=root` -- the binding tries to find a property UC1 provided/owned by that "root" element. Is "root" *the* SetupUC element?

Comment: UC1 is changing in the textbox, tbx1. When the data it is bound to in the Main Window changes, it changes simultaneously in textbox tx1 in the User Control.
What I cannot figure out is how to reference the the value of UC1 in the ViewModel program
Sorry, if I am being unclear, etc., I have just started C# programming and come from a non-OO programming background.

Comment: Based on the updated code, it should work. I guess you make somewhere a mistake during debugging. Since you are new to OO, please double-check whether your code does (by accident or intentionally) creates more than one *SetupViewModel* object, and that you are actually inspecting the particular *SetupViewModel* object which is used for the data binding with *ViewModelStringProperty*.

Comment: Note that your binding in code-behind explicitely uses the created *SetupViewModel* as its source- changing the *DataContext* of SetupUC at a later point of time would not change the source of that binding. Thus, if by any chance your code/XAML replaces the DataContext with yet another *SetupViewModel* object, the binding you made in code-behind will still work on the original *SetupViewModel* object (as this object has been set explicitely as the binding source). If this scenario is indeed the case, you could perhaps by mistake inspect the wrong *SetupViewModel* object (in the DataContext)...

Comment: Come to think of it perhaps it is better to do your binding in code-behind like this: `new Binding("ViewModelStringProperty") { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };`. Note that there is no source specified, which makes the binding look for the *ViewModelStringProperty* property in whatever object is provided by SetupUC's DataContext. Since you assigned *svm* to SetupUC.DataContext i assume that your intent is actually to let the binding work on whatever object is stored in SetupUC.DataContext. If another object is assigned to the DataContext, the binding will automatically work on that other object...

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.
I am trying to do the binding as noted in the code behind. I tried with source specified and w/o; also, I only use DataContext once across the code behind, and now at all in the XAML. The code behind is:
    public SetupUC()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SetupViewModel svm = new SetupViewModel();
            this.DataContext = svm;
            Binding binding = new Binding("ViewModelStringProperty") { Source = svm, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, SetupUC.UC1Property, binding);

        }

Comment: Well, you will need to debug more extensively and thoroughly to find out what is going on there in your code. I am really not sure what your software is doing. What i mentioned before are typical pitfalls/mistakes, but there could be as many other things your code is doing wrong or in unintended manners as there are ways to skin a cat...

Answer (score 0):

To ensure your changes in your `TextBox` are immediately pushed to the `DependencyProperty` and subsequently the view-model, ensure you have `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on your `TextBox.Text` binding, i.e.:

```
Text="{Binding UC1, ElementName=root, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

With this, my example worked perfectly fine.

If this doesn't help, I suggest adding two additional `TextBlocks`, one bound to the `UC1` and one bound to `ViewModelStringProperty`, this will make it easier to tell which are getting updated correctly, e.g.:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding UC1, ElementName=Root, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding UC1, ElementName=Root}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ViewModelStringProperty}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: UC1 is displaying, updating fine. It's binding it to ViewModelStringProperty that does not seem to be working, or I have constructed incorrectly. I did try the above and both textbox/blocks related to UC1 display correctly, ViewModelStringProperty display nothing. I am using the UpdateSourceTrigger.

Comment: I am not too sure then, I have implemented my code almost identical to yours (but with only one OnPropertyChanged method so it compiles) and it works absolutely fine. I will upload my project in a zip so you can compare and confirm mine works.

Comment: @stephen [here](http://1drv.ms/1m2y8Uh) is a link to a project I created to demonstrate the WPF chained bindings. Give that a go and see if it works for you.

Comment: wow, good stuff. I downloaded your project, worked exactly as expected. Next, I implemented it as a UC in my Main Window (same way as in the downloaded project). Again, everything is fine. Finally, bound data in Main Window to UC1, does not work entirely. The first 2 text blocks still change together, but the last text block bound to ViewModelStringProperty does not. The one line I changed in the Main Window XAML was:  
  
    <UCV:SetupUC2 />  
to  <br/>
    <UCV:SetupUC2 UC1="{Binding Path=DataContext.ContainerData, ElementName=winCon, Mode=OneWay}"> </UCV:SetupUC2>

Comment: @stephen and that line change is your problem, you are replacing the binding on `UC1`, only one binding can exist on a `DependencyProperty` at a time, it can either be bound to `SetupViewModel.ViewModelStringProperty` or `DataContext.ContainerData`, not both.

Comment: Arggg! So, now that my objective seems pretty clear, any ideas on how to skin that cat?